# Dataframes python removing duplicates

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
  TaskID Status         Time         
0    123   Progress     12.00
1    234   Progress     12.10
2    123   Almost Done  12.20
3    234   Completed    12.40
```

I need to update the Status of the records with the latest records without changing the values of the other columns and delete the latest duplicate records.

**Final Result**

```
   TaskID Status         Time         
0    123   Almost Done  12.00
1    234   Completed    12.10
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and 
[`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.groupby('TaskID', as_index=False).agg({'Status':'last','Time':'first'})
print (df)
   TaskID       Status  Time
0     123  Almost Done  12.0
1     234    Completed  12.1
```